# Problema de fazer update com 1 campo - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Segue o código:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var t = new MinhaTabela
    {
        MeuCampo= 10
    };
    db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Definição da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MinhaTabela] (
    [MeuCampo] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MinhaTabela] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MeuCampo] ASC)
```

Depois da linha : `db.SaveChanges();` não acontece nada e não muda o valor.

Não estou conseguindo modificar o valor 9 para 10. O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse código não modifica nada. Você está criando um objeto novo e tentando salvar este objeto novo usando uma operação de atualização. Como esse objeto novo ainda não existe em banco de dados, a operação de atualização falha.

O correto seria você selecionar o registro, atualizar e depois salvar de novo.

```
var registro = db.MinhaTabela.FirstOrDefault(a => a.MeuCampo == 9);
registro.MeuCampo = 10;
db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Dá erro: `The property 'MeuCampo' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.`

Comment: Chaves não podem ser modificadas por definição. Apenas excluindo o registro e inserindo outro.